# Migration issue Angular 8 to 9

Tags: angular9, ng-bootstrap-modal

I'm updating my angular project to use angular 9. In angular 8 I was using *ng5-bootstrap-modal*, but now I'm getting error:

> ERROR in node_modules/ng5-bootstrap-modal/dist/bootstrap-modal.module.d.ts:4:22
>
> - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of SharedModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> This likely means that the library (ng5-bootstrap-modal) which
> declares BootstrapModalModule has not been processed correctly by
> ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version
> of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking
> with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be
> compatible with Ivy.

Did anyone face the same issue?

Comment: Could you resolve de issue?

Comment: today i am facing this